# switch frame by class name webdriverio

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I'm try switch frame, but they ID and Name attribute is dynamic. I'm used webdriverio. Can i use class name? any ideas?

```
<iframe id="n33l4d68f0xr" class="KA-JQ" name="n33l4d68f0xr" src="https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com&hl=en&hostId=gmail-to&multiselectEnabled=true&navHidden=true&dff=0&authuser=0&title=Select%20contacts&relayUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Ffavicon.ico&nav=((%22contacts%22))&rpctoken=fmac4onpwdet&rpcService=n33l4d68f0xr" tabindex="0" frameborder="0">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all elements by selector and switch to first like this:

```
// inside some async func
const {value} = await browser.elements('.KA-JQ');
await browser.frame(value[0]);

// or not async
return browser.elements('.KA-JQ').then(iFrame => {
    return browser.frame(iFrame.value[0]);
});
```